# Morphai Array Slice[Aggregation Pipeline]

Tags: morphia

```
{ $project: { _id: 1, facets: { $slice: [ "$facets", 0,1] } } }

AggregationPipeline pipeline = ds.createAggregation
pipeline.project()
```

Need to write this mongo db query in morphia[AggregationPipeline.project]

Can you please help me to write this query in morphia

```
ArraySlice slice=new ArraySlice(searchRequisitionRequestBean.getOffset(),
    searchRequisitionRequestBean‌​.getLimit());
Query<Requisition> sliceQuery = ds.createQuery(Requisition.class);
sliceQuery.project("_id", true);
sliceQuery.project("facets", slice);
pipeline.project(sliceQuery.getQueryObject());
```

Comment: Could you please post what have you tried, your best attempt? Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to add code, the comments are difficult to read. Thanks.